# PHP. Почему функция fwrite возвращает больше байт чем длина записанного ею контента?

Tags: php

Перестал работать кэш на файлах в битриксе. Полез разбираться.
В методе сохранения кэша есть условие на тождественное равенство байт из функции fwrite с содержимым записанного. Если тождественно равно, кэш запишется.
Вот теперь не равно. Чуть-чуть больше.

```
$handle = fopen($fnTmp, "wb+")
$this->written = fwrite($handle, $contents);
$len = strlen($contents);
fclose($handle);
$tmpContent = file_get_contents($fnTmp);

Printu::obj($this->written)->title('write $this->written');
Printu::obj($len)->title('write $len');
Printu::obj(strlen($tmpContent))->title('write $tmpContent');

if ($this->written === $len) {
...
```

лог:

```
write $this->written: 212983
write $len: 210048
write $tmpContent: 210048
```

Comment: Подозреваю что у вас стоит `mbstring.func_overload` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mbstring.overload.php

Comment: так и напишите, в эпсилон окрестности `abs($written - $len) < $epsilon` :D

Comment: @mpakfm оформите ответом.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Алексей. Перепроверил, действительно в настройках php.ini стояло 2 Вообще ранее я менял эту настройку локально для этого хоста. Битрикс изменил правила. И все проверки проходили успешно. Настройка пхп показывала такое:
`Directive Local Value Master Value mbstring.func_overload 0 2`
Изменив сейчас корневую настройку в php.ini теперь настройка такая:
`Directive Local Value Master Value mbstring.func_overload 0 0`
Теперь циферки совпадают.